# Averaging numbers of array columns

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok I'm going to start with I suck at math and this is making my head spin so forgive me if I'm just being dumb. haha

I have an array or arrays that kind of looks like this, only with a ton more data in it.

```
[
 [3,4,6],
 [4,7,9],
 [3,8,9],
 [7,3,9]
]
```

And because it has so much data in it I need to average those values to put onto a graph. Some 600 plots on a graph would not be fun haha

But I don't want to average each individual array I need to average all the arrays together. Like average 3,4,3,7 and then so on. Does that make sense?

I already have a function that will average an array, but my mind can't wrap around how to do this.

```
average: function() {
            var cnt, tot, i;
            cnt = arguments.length;
            tot = i = 0;
            while (i < cnt) tot+= arguments[i++];
            return tot / cnt;
        },
```

Any help will be appreciated and will stop me from throwing the computer out the window. :)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: why not fuse all the arrays in one big array to average?

Comment: @DouglasBarbin So the array of arrays above I need to average the numbers and make it into one array of those averages. So average 3,4,3,7 and then 4, 7, 8,3 and then 6,9,9,6

Comment: @ionutioio I'm not really sure what you mean? I have some 600 of these with much more data in each.

Comment: @KingMarvel That's just one array, I'm trying to compare from different arrays

Comment: create an unique array with the averages of all your small arrays and then average those. think recursively.

Comment: @ionutioio It's already an array of arrays and they are by no means small

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var twoDimArr = [
  [3, 4, 6],
  [4, 7, 9],
  [3, 8, 9],
  [7, 3, 9]
];
for (var i = 0; i < twoDimArr[0].length; i++) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < twoDimArr.length; j++) {
    sum += twoDimArr[j][i];
  }
  var avg = sum / twoDimArr.length;
  console.log(avg);
}
```

Comment: Does this yield an average of averages?  Or just the average of all the elements?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, I understood that the OP wants the average of 'columns' in the array, so this is what it does

Comment: @zazvorniki, ive been there :)

Answer (score 0):

The arrays are just in the wrong format.  But that is ok.  This can be fixed with a loop.  This code loops through them and stores the sum, count, and average for each as it goes through them.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script>
// sample data
var samarr = [[1,2,3],[3,7,9],[2,8,4],[6,2,2],[9,1,5]];
// new array that holds total for each column (0,1,2); in each I am storing 3 values (sum,count, avg).
var newarray = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];


//for each array in sample data...
for(i = 0; i < samarr.length; i++){
    //for each element in the array
    for(j=0; j<samarr[i].length; j++){
        //put the data in the new array
        //this keeps a rolling value of the sum
        newarray[j][0] += samarr[i][j];
        //this keeps a rolling value of the number of elements
        newarray[j][1]++;
        //this keeps a rolling value of the average
        newarray[j][2] = newarray[j][0]/newarray[j][1];
    }
}

//This dumps the new array to an alert box. ;-)
alert(newarray);
</script
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean they are in the wrong format? I don't think I understand what you are getting at?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the way to get the averages the way it is asked is not straightforward the way the data is organized.  In other words, if the data was in arrays based on which groups of data were going to be averaged together, they would look like [[3,4,3,7,...],[4,7,8,3,...],...].  It would just be a matter of grabbing the first array and working with it and then go to the next.  Since the data is not organized that way, the best way to handle it is looping through and either reorganize the data to the desired way or keep running tallies as I have done.

Comment: You have picked AmmarCSE's answer already which is basically the same method so I will leave it at that.